# Substitute Pauli Operators in SymPy

Tags: operators, sympy, physics, symbolic-math

I want to calculate the trace of a tensor product of Pauli matrices but I'm not sure if it is possible.

```py
import sympy as sp

from sympy.physics.quantum import TensorProduct as ts

from sympy.physics.matrices import msigma
from sympy.physics.quantum import qapply

from sympy.physics.paulialgebra import Pauli
from sympy.physics.quantum import tensor_product_simp as tpsimp

sI , sx, sy ,sz = 1, Pauli(1), Pauli(2),Pauli(3)
Id, x, y, z = sp.eye(2), msigma(1), msigma(2), msigma(3)

convrt = {sI:Id, sx:x, sy:y, sz:z}

r = ts(sx,sy,sz,sI)
print(tpsimp(qapply(r.subs(convrt))).doit())
```

The result is:

[image]

But I expected a 16x16 Matrix:

[image]

With the result I got I can't calculate the trace of the matrix. Is it possible to do it? This is just an small example, my `r` isn't easy like this one, it involve functions and some constants  and has more terms but my main problem is to convert properly tensor products of Pauli operators to a matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation of the `TensorProduct`, it states:

> For matrices, this uses `matrix_tensor_product` to compute the Kronecker or tensor product matrix. For other objects a symbolic `TensorProduct` instance is returned.

In particular, `r` is a tensor product of symbolic objects. When you substitute the matrices:

```py
expr = r.subs(convrt)
```

This is a tensor product of matrices, but because it was originally a tensor product of symbolic object, the `matrix_tensor_product` was never called.

I would consider [opening an issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/) for this, and ask to implement an `as_explicit` method, just like what's found on matrix expressions.

Usually, I would reconstruct the object (the tensor product in this case) with this syntax, in order to force the `matrix_tensor_product` to be executed:

```py
expr.func(*expr.args)
```

However, this still doesn't evaluate the product. Note that your Pauli matrices are instances of `Matrix` (alias of `MutableDenseMatrix`). But when we substituted them into the symbolic tensor product, somewhere they were changed to `ImmutableDenseMatrix`. Sadly, the constructor of `TensorProduct` looks for instances of `Matrix`, hence `ImmutableDenseMatrix` are considered as symbolic objects. In my opinion, there are two bugs:

1. The conversion from `MutableDenseMatrix` to `ImmutableDenseMatrix` shouldn't have happened.
2. The constructor of `TensorProduct` should also look for instances of `ImmutableDenseMatrix`.

All of this to say that your are forced to execute the undocumented `matrix_tensor_product`:

```py
from sympy.physics.quantum.matrixutils import matrix_tensor_product
matrix_tensor_product(*expr.args)
```